# Inline edit shows wrong row to edit in gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a nested gridview and after I page my nested gridview and click edit, it show row values of first gridview page. 
This is the code for my edit.

```
   protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gvTemp = (GridView)sender;
    gvUniqueID = gvTemp.UniqueID;
    gvEditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: you are calling gridview2 rowediting method and binding gridview1 what is this..

Comment: @Rahul Its a nested gridview. Please see this link. (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20047/Editable-Nested-GridView-All-in-One) .